# Inserting elements before and after content

Tags: html, css

I have a headline and I want to insert a block with a certain background before and after the headline with the CSS pseudo elements :before and :after, and I want all them to float left so they're in one line.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to select the actual content of an element. Let's see this example realized with DIVs:

HTML:

```
<div class="line"></div>
<h1>Text here</h1>
<div class="line"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.line {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    background-color: grey;
}

h1 {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

So this will work. However, is there a way to realize the same with the :before and :after elements for h1? Can I somehow select the "Text here" and apply the :after class to it?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Let me explain this in a different way. See this link: [link]http://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/

I want to achieve the same as the last example, only instead of inserting the text via `content: "$";` in the CSS, I want that dollar-sign to be inserted as a `<h1>`-element - ergo the "hr" to wrap around the h1.

Comment: _“I can't figure out how to select the actual content of an element”_ – what “content” do you want to select? And what does your given example have to do with an `hr` element?

Comment: just as I said in the last sentence "I want that dollar-sign to be inserted as a <h1>-element - ergo the "hr" to wrap around the h1"

see the solution below by @invot

Comment: What dollar sign? There is no dollar sign in the HTML you have shown and that you said achieves what you want – and neither is there a dollar sign in invot’s answer …

Comment: nah... I'm referring to the link stated above ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want something like this:

```
 h1, h1:before, h1:after {
   display:inline-block;
   float:left;
}

h1 {
   height: 16px;
   width: auto;
   position:relative;
   padding:0 20px;
}

h1:before {
   content: " ";
   background:url(...);
   height: 16px;
   width: 16px;
   position:absolute;
   left:0; 
}


h1:after {
   content: " ";
   background:url(...);
   height: 16px;
   width: 16px;
   position:absolute;
   right:0; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I meant. This just adds the elements on top and on bottom of the headline.

Let me explain this in a different way. See this link: [link]http://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/

I want to achieve the same as the last example, only instead of inserting the text via `content: "$";` in the CSS, I want that dollar-sign to be inserted as a `<h1>`-element - ergo the "hr" to wrap around the h1.

Comment: thanks, that's what I meant! great! stackoverflow is awesome ;)